# Regex for extensive phone number validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number of rules which I need to apply to a phone number input field, following is my attempt:

```
var positive_checks = new Array(
    /^[0-9]{8}$/g    // 1. Must have 8 digits exactly
);

var negative_checks = new Array(
    /^[0147]/g,      // 2. Must not start with 0,1,4 or 7
    /^[9]{3}/g,      // 3. Must not start with 999
    /(.)\\1*$/g      // 4. Must not be all the same number
);

for (i in positive_checks) {
    if (str.search(positive_checks[i]) < 0) {
        return false;
    }
}

for (i in negative_checks) {
    if (str.search(negative_checks[i]) >= 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

All rules are working except rule 4, which I don't fully understand, other than it uses back-references somehow. I think there was mention that the environment needs to allow for back-references, is Javascript such an environment?

Secondarily, I'd be interested to try and rework all rules so I only need to have a single rule array and loop and not need to check for negative checks, is that possible in each of these instances? Ultimately I'm looking for a Javascript solution, however being able to use regex for all 4 makes it nicer looking code in my opinion, and being form validation logic means that performance is not really an issue here.

Comment: Hmmm -2, what did I do?!

Comment: which country do you need to validate the phone numbers in?

Comment: You post code you don't understand and expect to be served a full solution to your very specific problem that you do not explain, that's why the downvotes

Comment: @xShirase Hong Kong, although these validation rules were requested specifically for my current project, I don't have any background on why they are required, other than I guess anything starting with 999 will immediately call emergency services.

Comment: I think the fourth rule needs a `^` in the beginning. Otherwise it rejects everything.

Comment: The code above I wrote entirely myself other than the line for #4 which I copy-pasted from an SO answer, so I understand all of it except one line, I'm trying to understand that one line really.

Comment: Thanks @IngoBürk unfortunately that still seems to let everything through.

Comment: http://regexr.com/39khr hover the different parts to see what they do

Comment: Awesome link @xShirase thanks! Looks like I just needed to remove one of the `\` to make `/(.)\1*$/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number four rule probably doesn't work because of the double backslashes you have for your backreference and I would also anchor it and change the `*` quantifier to `+` meaning "one or more times"

```
/^(.)\1+$/g
```

Explanation:

```
^      # the beginning of the string
(      # group and capture to \1:
  .    #   any character except \n
)      # end of \1
  \1+  #   what was matched by capture \1 (1 or more times)
$      # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

A one-liner that will validate all of your requirements:

```
var re = /^(?=.{8}$)(?!999|[0147]|(.)\1+)[0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Just to point this out: I don't think the oneliner is am improvement, quite the opposite. It makes maintaining validation logic by far more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: I agree, one liner in this instance is just showing off, but I like to try and read them as I find them hard to compile.

Comment: definitely true, think of the next developper... or you could add a massive comment block, which would take more space than the 4 rules combined...

Comment: Yeah, it's fun to try boiling them down as practice. By the way I think the anchor (`^`) is definitely needed. Just because it sounds like it's optional here. Wouldn't it reject everything without that?

Comment: @xShirase a comment block would make it neither easier to read nor easier to maintain. It would just explain what it does (hopefully, assuming the comment is correct and up to date). For any change you'd still have to "parse" the expression yourself. Comments are rarely the answer :)

Comment: I necessarily do not think this is about "showing off", more of a way to make things less complicated by compiling four different expressions. But that is my opinion and I write/debug/benchmark regex on a daily basis.

Comment: @IngoBürk true. Always think of the poor guy who will come after you. http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882 is the book that enlightened me on that, and many other subjects, it has a full section on comments :)

Comment: @xShirase I read exactly the same book ;) indeed a very good recommendation

Answer (score 1):

Use [regexr.com/39khr](http://regexr.com/39khr)  and hover the different parts of your expression to see what they do.

As you do not say what doesn't work, ie: giving examples of a false number that should be true or the other way around, it's very hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Understood, I'll be more forthcoming about false positives in future, thanks for the link it'll help a lot.